# html/code - Divert to desktop/mobile site on enter the site

Tags: php, html, web

I'm working on a site with separate pages for mobile and desktop. I have a code that diverts people to mobile or desktop based on screen resolution.

**I want to change this so the code only runs On Domain/Website Load - for example: IfPreviousDomain != this Domain run code.... (www.example.com)**

The code we have now looks like this:

```
<script> if ( (screen.width < 1024) && (screen.height < 768) ) { 
window.location = 'http://www.example.com/Mobile.html';
}  </script>
```

OR

```
<script> if ( (screen.width > 1024) && (screen.height > 768) ) { 
window.location = 'http://www.example.com/';
}  </script>
```

if there is better code for the job please let me know. Also I only know basic html and Python so I don't even know what language the above code is.

Comment: use http://mobiledetect.net/ with that you can check the device of the user server side instead of client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language above is JavaScript. I don't see any better option than the version above. If you wrap your code with

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //here goes your code
});
```

then the function should only be executed on the initial load.

Comment: hello - would I put this in the head section of the page or elsewhere?